# Parsing json array having one-to- many relationship

Tags: android, json, one-to-many, server

I have a JSON array coming from server, which has categories, each categories have two, three questions, and each questions have answers in the form of 'yes' and 'no'.

I have created three class, one for categories, one for questions, and one for answers. The categories class has arraylist of questions and question class has arraylist of answers.

I need to fetch the category name, and populate the spinner with the category name, after that once I select a category from spinner, all question and answers related to that category should appear.

I have already parse the json, and populated the spinner with categories name, but I need to know, how I can map that category with its corresponding questions and answers.

The format of JSON is below:

```
    [
    {     
     "categoryName": "color1",   
     "colorCategoryQuestions": [
     {

     "question": "Is it blue?",       
     "colorCategoryQuestionOptions": [
            {

                    "optionText": "Yes"

             },
            {

                    "optionText": "No"

             }
        ],       
      },
     {

         "question": "Is it red?",       
         "colorCategoryQuestionOptions": [
             {

                 "optionText": "Yes",

             },
             {

                    "optionText": "No",

            }
        ],       
      },

     ],

     },

     {     
             "categoryName": "color2",   
            "colorCategoryQuestions": [
           {

                "question": "Is it blue?",       
                "colorCategoryQuestionOptions": [
                 {

                    "optionText": "Yes"

               },
               {

                    "optionText": "No"

                }
          ],       
        },
      {

     "question": "Is it red?",       
     "colorCategoryQuestionOptions": [
             {

                 "optionText": "Yes",

             },
             {

                    "optionText": "No",

            }
        ],       
      },

     ],

    },

   ]
```

Comment: Why not create a `Questions` table, with with every questions inserted into it, with the `categoryName` as one field in it. So once when the `categoryName` is selected in the spinner, you could fetch the data from the table and show them

Comment: the json you have posted is not a valid json (as issues when validated on jsonlint.com)

Answer (score 0):

I maybe be misunderstanding, but wouldn't it be easier to just have one class to represent the triplet of category, question, and answer? For example:

```
public class QuizItem{

     private String category;
     private String question;
     private int answer;

     public QuizItem(String category, String question, int answer) {
          super();
          this.category = category;
          this.question = question;
          this.answer = answer;
}

...
```

Then all associations are already linked. You can store these as objects in an `ArrayList`, and traverse it to pull out what you need by category, etc. That said, maybe you don't even need the class to model the data. Maybe you can just store the JSON objects as they are, stick them in `ArrayList`, and traverse it to pull out what you need using the standard JSON library tools.